# Building up to distance at required speed

Tags: running, training

I need to be able to run 2.4k in about 12.5 minutes, which means I can basically do the whole run at 12kmh.

I can't do anywhere near that. I can just about run about half of that at 8kmh with a 12kmh push for the last 100/200m.

So, I'm thinking, I add an extra hundred metres to that final push every few runs til the whole thing is at that speed, then add hundred metre increments to the run until I hit the distance.

What I'm wondering though, is would I be better off walk/running the whole distance and then gradually increasing the running intervals?

Or does it not really matter?

Comment: What is the timeframe for this? When do you need to be able to run this distance at that speed? (Military or similar test I assume?)

Comment: Are you ever running further than 2.4K? You'd be better off increasing the running distance and then you'll fine that the shorter distances at higher speeds become easier.

Comment: @JohnP - that's exactly it, but not in any rush, I'm taking my time with things as I've spent the last 5 years recovering from an ankle injury and many rounds of surgery

Comment: @TheFootsie - Probably at some point but it's not something I would like to do now unless it would make hitting that target in the medium term easier

Comment: @ScottishTapWater - There is no substitute at all for distance. Scout7 used to say "Run. Run lots. Mostly easy, sometimes fast". That's the best generic formula to get faster at running that I know of. (As you can see, I use that a lot - https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7309/should-i-run-everyday-or-alternate-days-and-run-longer/7312#7312)

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I think it would help in the medium term. I would up the distance to 5k, it'll be horrible for a month and then you'll suddenly realise you're doing it without a problem. Maybe follow a couch to 5k plan? On the injury front its very sensible to not want to aggravate previous injuries but I'd say that trying to run 2.4k at a faster speed than you're fit enough for is just as likely to cause injury as running further distances.